# How can I convert types in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, types

I'm using two different libraries in my project, and both of them supply a basic rectangle `struct`. The problem with this is that there seems to be no way to insert a conversion between the types, so I can't call a function in one library with the result from a function in the other. If I was the author of either of these, I could create conversions, from the outside, I can't.

library a:

```
typedef struct rectangle { sint16 x; sint16 y; uint16 w; uint16 h; } rectangle;
```

library b:

```
class Rect {
  int x; int y; int width; int height;
  /* ... */
};
```

Now, I can't make a converter `class`, because C++ will only look for a conversion in one step. This is probably a good thing, because there would be a lot of possibilities involving creating new objects of all kinds of types.

I can't make an operator that takes the `struct` from `a` and supplies an object of the `class` from `b`:

```
foo.cpp:123 error: ‘operator b::Rect(const rectangle&)’ must be a nonstatic member function
```

So, is there a sensible way around this?

### edit:

I should perhaps also point out that I'd really like some solution that makes working with the result seamless, since I don't expect to be that coder. (Though I agree, old-school, explicit, conversion would have been a good choice. The other branch, [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) has the same problem..)

### edit2:

Actually, none of the suggestions really answer my actual question, [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) seems to be correct. C++ actually can't do this. Sucks, but true. (If it makes any difference, I'm going to try subclassing as suggested by [CodingTheWheel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90/codingthewheel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify the structures then you have no alternative to writing a manual conversion function because overloading conversion operators only works within the class body. There's no other way.

Answer (score 4):

Create an intermediate shim type "`RectangleEx`", and define custom conversions to/from the 3rd-party string types. Whenever you speak to either API, do so through the shim class.

Another way would be to derive a `class` from either `rect` or `Rectangle`, and insert conversions/constructors there.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how sensible this is, but how about something like this:

```
class R
{
public:
    R(const rectangle& r) { ... };
    R(const Rect& r) { ... };

    operator rectangle() const { return ...; }
    operator Rect() const { return ...; }

private:
    ...
};
```

Then you can just wrap every `rectangle` in `R()` and the "right thing" will happen.

Comment: May be this is not the case, but -in general- having more than one outstanding implicit conversion may result in ambiguity in expressions: suppose both rectangle and Rect have an & operator:
Suppose you have 

R ra, rb;
ra & rb;

The & operation is ambiguous (can be both the rectangle and the Rect one)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be feasible in your case, but I've seen people employ a little preprocessor-foo to massage the types into compatibility.

Even this assumes that you are building one or both libraries.

It is also possible that you don't want to do this at all, but want to re-evaulate some early decision. Or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the `struct`s were the same internally, you could do a [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast); however, since it looks like you have 16-bit vs 32-bit fields, you're probably stuck converting on each call, or writing wrappers for all functions of one of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simple like this: (note this may/probably won't compile) but you get the idea...

```
private Rect* convert(const rectangle& src)
{
    return new Rect(src.x,src.y,src.w,src.h);
}
int main()
{
    rectangle r;
    r.x = 1;
    r.y = 2;
    r.w = 3;
    r.h = 4;

    Rect* foo = convert(&r);
    ...
    delete foo;

}
```

**EDIT:** Looks like koko's and I have the same idea.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try it with operator overloading ? (Maybe a = operator which is not a method of your class) ?

Rect operator= (const Rect&,const rectangle&)

More about this in the C++ programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup or maybe on this page: http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: It is not legal in C++ to define operator= outside a class.